# Using Loop To Select/Remove Options From Listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, listbox, visual-web-developer-2010

So basically I am using a FOR loop to add and remove options from a listbox. 
It functions correctly when selected 1 option (from either remove or select) and it functions correctly when I select two separate options (For example, item[0] and item[4]).

However, I am having trouble when I try to select all options or when I select two items that are side by side ([2],[3].. etc)

Here is my loop for the select function:

```
protected void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < lbSnacks.Items.Count; intCounter++)
    {
        if (lbSnacks.Items[intCounter].Selected) // if the snack is selected
        { // add the listitem to the lbSelected listbox
            lbSelected.Items.Add(lbSnacks.Items[intCounter]);
        }

    }
    for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < lbSnacks.Items.Count; intCounter++)
    {
        if (lbSnacks.Items[intCounter].Selected) // if the snack is selected
        { // add the listitem to the lbSelected listbox
            lbSnacks.Items.Remove(lbSnacks.Items[intCounter]);
        }

    }
}
```

The error is basically taking the item and putting it into the "selected" listbox but it is leaving behind one of the two options in the original "snacks" box.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, when you remove an item, all of the other items shift downwards - which means the next loop iteration (since it increments your index) "skips" one item.

There are various ways to handle this.  The simplest is to just loop backwards:

```
for (int intCounter = lbSnacks.Items.Count-1; intCounter >= 0; intCounter--)
{
    if (lbSnacks.Items[intCounter].Selected) // if the snack is selected
    { // add the listitem to the lbSelected listbox
        lbSelected.Items.Add(lbSnacks.Items[intCounter]);
        lbSnacks.Items.Remove(lbSnacks.Items[intCounter]);
    }
}
```

This way, when the items "shift", it doesn't matter, since you've already dealt with those items.

Comment: Thank you so much Reed! 
I am struggling learning loops but I've been practicing and starting to get the hang of it.